# Fetch npm package versions using jFrog REST API

Tags: angular, npm, artifactory, jfrog-cli

I am trying to get the versions of an NPM package published on jFrog artifactory.
I can do a similar thing with NPM registry using the following URL: 
https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash

However, there is no such feature available in jFrog or if it is there, I am not able to find one.

I need to use the versions of a particular package in my angular application, so CLI commands won't work for me.

Answer (score 2):

You can retrieve the package versions by using the next REST Api:

```
http://<Artifactory Ip>:<Port>/artifactory/api/npm/<Npm repository key>/<Package name>
```